# How can I make this circuit work?

Tags: mosfet, push-pull

I have a need for a push pull circuit which can drive a line to either +12V, -12V or leave the line floating. The circuit needs to be able to source and sink 2 amperes to and from the line.

A 5V microcontroller is to control 2 transistors which should control the 2 mosfets

[image]

The general idea is that R3 keeps Q2 off by pulling the gate of Q1 to the source so that Vgs = 0V. Liikewise, R6 should pull the gate of Q1 to the source so that Q2 is also off in idle state.

Will this circuit work like I hope it will work?

EDIT:
I completely forgot about the forward diode effect of the MOSFETs. As such I shorted the +12V to -12V directly.

I have no real need for a galvanic isolation. It was merely the best thing I could come up with. I believe I can replace them by conventional transistors

EDIT2:
I replaced the optocouplers by a pair of transistors. And I fixed the symbols for the mosfets.

I think with this schematic that the P channel MOSFET will work but I am not 100% sure about the N channel. If Q4 is on, the Vgs of Q1 will be aprox. 12V + (5V - 0.7V) = 16.3V. This N channel mosfet is a P65NF06 and can handle a Vgs of 20V.

Comment: Do you need galvanic isolation, or is this just the best way you've found to do this?

Comment: Optos tend to be slow. So, this (modified to avoid Vgs limitations) had better be for on/off control, not PWM.

Comment: Blast! I totally forgot about the diode functionality of mosfet. Real silly as you can clearly see them in the sechamatic

I have indeed no need for galvanic isolation.It was merely the best I came up with.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You have your MOSFETs placed incorrectly; it should be a P channel at the top and an N channel lower down. There may be other problems but this one sprung out as obvious.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't.

The N-channel FET has Vgs maximum of +/- 8V, it will be exceeded and it is almost sure to get damaged after applying 24V potential difference.

The P-channel FET has Vgs maximum of +/- 20V, it will be exceeded and it might get damaged too.

Comment: If only electronics would just work the way we *imagine* it does, things would be so much easier.